# integrating R programming with java

Tags: java, r

I'm Trying to perform Example-1 From Rjava folder, I have Installed JRI.jar,JAREngine.jar, REngine.jar in my Libraries in netbeans,and also given a these 3 path to user and System variable:`C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri\i386;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri\x64;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri;`

System : Both 32/64bit R is installed and accessed.

But it is Showing me Error message :

```
Error:
Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri\i386\jri.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
    at rtest.Rtest.main(Rtest.java:69)
```

Comment: If you're running 64-bit R, you have to install 64-bit Java as well.

Comment: I am using both 32 and 64 bit Version of R,and included both .jar file,so how can these be a issue?

Comment: jar file is one thing, `java` executable is another. What does `java -version` report as the current version/bit-ness?

Comment: java version is  64 Bit Server.after i removed a variable-path of 32 bit R,It is showing me error :                                                                     `Cannot find JRI native  library!                                                            
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.`

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`

Comment: I don't know how to deal with this error : ** `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries` **

Comment: Problem Solved : Add this Command at the begging of the  bat file:`set R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\;`   Location of bat File `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri `

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved** : Add this Command at the begging of the bat file:**set R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\;** Location of bat File **C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library\rJava\jri**